# How can I make input boxes with button dynamically on jquery dialog box?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make input boxes with a buttons dynamically on **jQuery dialog** box. 
Also I want to remove the input box, when I click a button.

Currently I am able to create button and input box. But, any kind of events on the newly created html elements does not working. So I am not able to remove the created input boxes.

Any solution for this?

Comment: read about [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thanks for the help it work

Comment: glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event delegation` on button events

> $(document).on('click','.remove', function() { will bind the event on the .remove elements which are not present at the time of binding event. This is called event delegation

```
$(document).on('click','.remove', function() {
    // your code here
})
```